# How to Modify InstallSheild setup.ilg file

Tags: c#, installshield, uninstallation

Can I modify InstallShield setup.ilg File?

I have install my program in C:\Program Files\MyProg using "InstallSheild". Now I want to copy the "MyProg" folder to some other computer and want my program to reside in D:. I will have to copy the "InstallSheild Installation Information" folder to the target computer, and write the registry as well, so that it could be uninstalled from control panel.

Now the problem is that setup.ilg file of the install shield has the path where it was originally installed, that is "C:\Program Files\MyProg", and I want to change it to "D:\MyProg".

Is it possible to change it using C#.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to heavily edit your topic line and the body of your question.  It looks to me like your REAL question is "how do I move an installed program from one drive and directory to a completely different location, while maintaining all functionality including uninstallability?"

I'll post an answer to THAT question if you ask it, but the short answer is, it's safest to back everything up, uninstall, then reinstall in the new location.  You never know what kind of path dependencies that the application EXPECTS the installer to have set up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but an ilg file is an Install Script log file, so I am unsure why you want to edit it?

It sounds to me like you want to move an installed program from one computer to another.

If it is a program you have created an installer for using installshield go back to your original installer designer and make the changes.

Other than that, what you doing is just just moving a program to another computer so I wouldn't worry about the ilg file you can just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

No, setup.ilg is a proprietary binary file. However in the same directory you will find setup.exe which you can execute as RickWeb mentioned.
The IS log contains what happened while installing the software on a particular computer. This information may later used within an update.

More important is the registry entry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`...